# IP Network Best Practice

Tags: networking, ip, best-practices

On my On Premise network we use IP Span 172.17.101.0-172.17.103.254
I should now connect our Windows Azure network to the On Premise network using VPN. Is it okay to use IP Span 172.16.1.0 in the Azure network. Or is it any best practice to follow here?

Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term "Best Practice" is getting a bit outdated, as there are a million different ways to achieve something.

That being said - avoiding overlapping of IP subnets makes your life a lot easier, as you remove the need for a advanced firewall with double NAT'ing.

You're not overlapping now, so I see no issues.